Ubuntu WiFi driver keeps crashing when trying to connect to WiFi network
After reinstalling Ubuntu it didn't want to connect to my home WiFi. It did connect to the hotspot. After I somehow connected to the home Internet I installed flathub and restarted the computer. After rebooting, when I try to connect to the network, the settings application just crashes and it won’t connect to the WiFi. My laptop is msi gf63-thin uc11

Remove Flathub again. Connect -- via an Ethernet cable is easiest -- and do a full updare first before you try to install anything new.

Liam , before installing flathub , I updated and upgraded Ubuntu

:-( You did not say that. How were we supposed to know?

Just reinstalled system lol
Everything works fine
